# Civ V Multiplayer - Change turn mode while in a game

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Me and my friends are enjoying a game of Civilization V, but when everyone got affected in a war - everything started to go so slow. That's because I selected hybrid turn mode by an accident when creating the game, so we take sequential turns when in war.

What I was wondering was if it was possible to change the turn mode to simultaneously when the game already has started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to change the turn mode - but it may not work if the game already started.

Try saving your game, and exiting. Host the game again via the Internet option, and ensure the game is private. BEFORE you invite your friend to the lobby, click on the 'game options' heading (small white text subtitle).. this should bring you to where all the game options are. You may be able to switch the turn mode from there.

Comment: It did unfortionatley not work, I'm only seeing the settings - but not able to change them. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I can confirm this only works for games that haven't yet been started. After the game's started you can see all the options but they can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple web app that will let you change the game parameters of a save file, including the turn mode: [Civilization V save editor](https://bmaupin.github.io/civ5save-editor/)

Just open your save file in the app and change the value under *Turn mode*. Then download the new save file with the changes and open it in the game.

The only other alternative I'm aware of would be to edit the save file by hand. This is the source I used for adding the functionality to my web app: http://blog.frank-mich.com/civilization-v-how-to-change-turn-type-of-a-started-game/